# SQL Query ignore subsequent distinct rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a table,

```
C_A C_B C_C  C_D
 mr  1  1000  d
 mrs 2  500   d
 mz  3  2500  d
 mrs 4  1500  d
```

I'd like to `SELECT` * `FROM` table `ORDER` `BY` C_C `DESC` but i'd like to ignore any subsequent (after the ordering) rows in which column A (C_A) is the same as rows that have a larger value in column C.

so it should look like:

```
C_A C_B C_C  C_D
 mz  3  2500  d
 mrs 4  1500  d
 mr  1  1000  d
```

when output

I've tried lots of different queries and sub queries in using `DISTINCT` and by grouping column C_A but I'm not competent enough in SQL in order to apply those to my example.

Any ideas on how I would be able to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I understood the problem. But this is perhaps what you're looking for:

```
select t1.*
from tablename t1
  join (select C_A, max(C_C) as maxcc
        from tablename
        group by C_A) t2
  on t1.C_A = t2.C_A and t1.C_C = t2.maxcc
```

Add `ORDER BY t1.C_C desc` at the end, if needed.

Comment: Perfect. I'm terrible at explaining things but you must have got what I meant. Works fine, will accept in a minute when I can :) Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Use **ROW_NUMBER()** AND **PARTITION By**

```
Declare @tblTest AS Table
(
    C_A VARCHAR(50),
    C_B  INT,
    C_C INT,
    C_D VARCHAR(50)
)


INSERT INTO @tblTest VALUES('mr',1,1000,'d')
INSERT INTO @tblTest VALUES('mrs',2,500,'d')
INSERT INTO @tblTest VALUES('mz',3,2500,'d')
INSERT INTO @tblTest VALUES('mrs',4,1500,'d')


SELECT 
    C_A ,
    C_B ,
    C_C ,
    C_D 
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        C_A ,
        C_B ,
        C_C ,
        C_D ,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition BY C_A Order by  C_A,C_D) AS PartNo
    FROM
    @tblTest
)X
WHERE X.PartNo=1
```